# Shp2pgsql-gui.exe - system error

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I have got this message when I was trying to run PostGIS 2.0 shapefile and dbf loader and exporter for first time. I tryed to reinstall but it did not run after second installation either. I have Win10 and PgAdmin4. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which PG version you are using ? In case of PG 11.0 you have rename certain dll file then reinstall postgis

Comment: check your encoding and SRID

Comment: Here is the answer that you were looking for- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792370/libsqlite3-0-dll-was-not-found-error-when-launching-shp2pgsql-gui-on-windows-po